# Display another page after waiting for the progress Bar to load in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, progress-bar

i just this module https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress in my iOS/ Android application and it's working fine. Now, i need to pass to a second page after loading the progress bar.. 
that's the code i used  for the progress bar :

constructor(props) {
        super(props);

```
    this.state = {
        progress: 0,
        indeterminate: true,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.animate();
}
animate() {
    let progress = 0;
    this.setState({ progress });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ indeterminate: false });
        setInterval(() => {
            progress += Math.random() / 5;
            if (progress > 1) {
                progress = 1;
                {Actions.second_page() }

            }
            this.setState({ progress });
        }, 500);
    }, 1500);
}
static propTypes = {
    openDrawer: React.PropTypes.func,
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <StatusBar hidden />
            <ProgressBar width={width} borderRadius={0}  borderColor={'white'} progress={this.state.progress}
                          indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}/>
                ...
```

So basically, i need to add an action when finishing loading (pass to another page when the progress = 1 ) ... Thank you

Comment: Paste the logic or whole class where you increase `this.setState({ progress: ++ });`

Comment: thank you @SagarKhatri i just updated the code above ..

Comment: you can add navigation code to `if (progress > 1)` block.

Comment: thanks i did and it's working BUT a very strange problem : now when clicking on any item in the drawer it takes me directly to that specified page in the ` if (progress > 1) ` code . It's like that the progress bar is still working and when the loading finishing it takes me back to that single page. i deleted that navigation line and the rest of the app is working fine . PS : i just used the progress bar in the first page but it seems that it's all over the app ..